# Trigger submit key not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site is [this](https://valgoverblik.dk/search/).

On the search form, if you type LA, a suggestion will appear. Try clicking on that with the mouse pointer. The Suggestion will go to the search box but the search results are not showing. Then you can press only enter key, the suggestion will show. Check [this](http://take.ms/vZim0) for understanding better.

I have used the below script to trigger the submit button after the value is selected:

```
jQuery("#form").submit();
```

But it is not working and the values are not showing.

What am I doing wrong?

What I want is user do not need to press enter key after the value is selected by the mouse pointer. Once the value is selected, the result will show automatically (without pressing enter).

Comment: I need to see more of your code.

Comment: Please create a minimal code example with which the problem can be reproduced. It is unlikely that someone is going to try to find their way in your site's code. More importantly, questions should be self-contained. Links to sites can be helpful, but should not contain important information that is not already in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should share the code instead of the website.

Though, I took a look at it and found that you are using `onkeyup` method to invoke the API.

```
<form id="form" class="p-relative">
          <input type="text" id="terms" autofocus class="awesomplete hs-input"  size="40" onkeyup="getScriptPage('show_results','terms','1')" onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) this.value = this.defaultValue" placeholder="Search for people, files & reports" onfocus="if ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) this.value = ''" value="Search for people, files & reports" data-list="Ada, Java, Bike, Bikemania, Lars Løkke Rasmussen" />
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-search hs-reset" data-ma-action="search-clear"></i>
        </form>
```

You should instead use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event on the textbox.

```
<input id="test" oninput="alert('blah')">
```